# Low latency video shared in local gigabit network using linux

Tags: linux, ffmpeg, video-streaming, latency, opencv

For a robotics task we need to share the video (Webcam) live to about 6 or 7 users in the same room. OpenCV will be used on the clients to read the situation and send new tasks to the robots. Latency should not be much more than one second, the lower the better. What commands would you recommend for this?

We have one camera on a Linux host which wants to share the video to about 6 other units just some meters away.

I already experimented with different setups. While raw-video looks like perfectly latency free (local loopback, the issue is the amount of data), any compression suddenly ads about a second delay.
And how should we share this in the network. Is broadcasting the right approach? How can it be so hard, they are right next to each other.

Works locally, issues over the network.

```
#server
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -r 10 -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -c:v libx264 -preset veryfast -tune zerolatency -pix_fmt yuv420p -f mpegts - | socat - udp-sendto:192.168.0.255:12345,broadcast
#client
socat -u udp-recv:12345,reuseaddr - | vlc --live-caching=0 --network-caching=0 --file-caching=0 -
```

raw video - perfectly fine like this, video with many artefacts if sent over the network

```
ffmpeg -f video4linux2 -r 10 -s 1280x720 -i /dev/video0 -c:v rawvideo -f rawvideo -pix_fmt yuv420p - | vlc --demux rawvideo --rawvid-fps 10 --rawvid-width 1280 --rawvid-height 720 --rawvid-chroma I420 -
```

The technology used doesen't matter, we do not care about network load either. Just want to use opencv on different clients using live data.

Comment: Moved Question from Stackoverflow, as it was put on hold there telling I should move it to superuser.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43825945/low-latency-video-shared-in-local-gigabit-network-using-linux

Comment: Broadcasting is definitely the right idea. However, what resolution and framerate are we talking about? 1280x720@10fps (=26,x MiB/s) should work without problems.

Comment: The Camera we currently use would be capable of (fullhd) 1920x1080 @30hz. Nothing against improved video quality. Just thought make it work first. Do you know the commands that should work? What encoding did you use to calculate the 26.x MiB/s?

Comment: That would be raw 24 bit RGB. You can easily check by inserting `pv -r` (“pipe view”) in your test pipe.

Comment: Maybe try [icecast](http://icecast.org/) if you need broadcasting anyway?

Comment: Oh yeah, I just had another thought: Without any buffering and without a proper stream format, would the receiver be able to tell when a frame starts and ends and when it has missed data?

Comment: I think that is actually what happened, and why it didn't work or only with lots of strange colored artefacts.
What would you recommend to do in order to avoid that?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

OS: Debian Stretch

```
cat /etc/*release
PRETTY_NAME="Debian GNU/Linux 9 (stretch)"
NAME="Debian GNU/Linux"
VERSION_ID="9"
VERSION="9 (stretch)"
ID=debian
HOME_URL="https://www.debian.org/"
SUPPORT_URL="https://www.debian.org/support"
BUG_REPORT_URL="https://bugs.debian.org/"

uname -v
#1 SMP Debian 4.9.25-1 (2017-05-02)

cvlc --version
VLC media player 2.2.6 Umbrella (revision 2.2.6-0-g1aae78981c)
VLC-Version 2.2.6 Umbrella (2.2.6-0-g1aae78981c)
Kompiliert von buildd auf binet.debian.org (May 24 2017 16:00:59)
Kompiler: gcc version 6.3.0 20170516 (Debian 6.3.0-18)
Dieses Programm kommt OHNE GEWÄHRLEISTUNG.
Sie dürfen das Programm unter den Bedingungen der GNU General Public License weitergegeben;
Für Details bitte die Datei COPYING ansehen.
Geschrieben von der VideoLAN-Gruppe; zu sehen in der AUTHORS-Datei.

ffplay -version
ffplay version 3.2.5-1 Copyright (c) 2003-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18) 20170516
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100

ffmpeg -version
ffmpeg version 3.2.5-1 Copyright (c) 2000-2017 the FFmpeg developers
built with gcc 6.3.0 (Debian 6.3.0-18) 20170516
configuration: --prefix=/usr --extra-version=1 --toolchain=hardened --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu --incdir=/usr/include/x86_64-linux-gnu --enable-gpl --disable-stripping --enable-avresample --enable-avisynth --enable-gnutls --enable-ladspa --enable-libass --enable-libbluray --enable-libbs2b --enable-libcaca --enable-libcdio --enable-libebur128 --enable-libflite --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-libfribidi --enable-libgme --enable-libgsm --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-libopenmpt --enable-libopus --enable-libpulse --enable-librubberband --enable-libshine --enable-libsnappy --enable-libsoxr --enable-libspeex --enable-libssh --enable-libtheora --enable-libtwolame --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libwavpack --enable-libwebp --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-libzmq --enable-libzvbi --enable-omx --enable-openal --enable-opengl --enable-sdl2 --enable-libdc1394 --enable-libiec61883 --enable-chromaprint --enable-frei0r --enable-libopencv --enable-libx264 --enable-shared
libavutil      55. 34.101 / 55. 34.101
libavcodec     57. 64.101 / 57. 64.101
libavformat    57. 56.101 / 57. 56.101
libavdevice    57.  1.100 / 57.  1.100
libavfilter     6. 65.100 /  6. 65.100
libavresample   3.  1.  0 /  3.  1.  0
libswscale      4.  2.100 /  4.  2.100
libswresample   2.  3.100 /  2.  3.100
libpostproc    54.  1.100 / 54.  1.100
```

ffplay /dev/video0

```
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':B sq=    0B f=0/0   
  Duration: N/A, start: 45810.627382, bitrate: 122880 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (YUY2 / 0x32595559), yuyv422, 640x480, 122880 kb/s, 25 fps, 25 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
```

--> yuyv422

Perfect pair (raw video):

**Server:**

```
cvlc -vvv v4l2:// :v4l2-dev=/dev/video0 :v4l2-width=640 :v4l2-height=480 :v4l2-fps 25 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=raw,dst=:8081}'
```

**Client:**

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuyv422 -video_size 640x480 -framerate 25 http://localhost:8081

(ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuyv422 -video_size 640x480 http://localhost:8081)
(ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuyv422 -video_size 640x480 http://server-ip:8081)
```

Sorry, don't have gbit-network nor 1080p-cam :(

For Raspberry Pi(3) users:

```
sudo modprobe bcm2835-v4l2
```

(No Display/X11 on the pi3)

```
ffprobe /dev/video0

ffprobe version N-85344-gb438a78 Copyright (c) 2007-2017 the FFmpeg developers
  built with gcc 4.9.2 (Raspbian 4.9.2-10)
  configuration: 
  libavutil      55. 60.100 / 55. 60.100
  libavcodec     57. 92.100 / 57. 92.100
  libavformat    57. 72.100 / 57. 72.100
  libavdevice    57.  7.100 / 57.  7.100
  libavfilter     6. 84.100 /  6. 84.100
  libswscale      4.  7.100 /  4.  7.100
  libswresample   2.  8.100 /  2.  8.100
Input #0, video4linux2,v4l2, from '/dev/video0':
  Duration: N/A, start: 153.062714, bitrate: 283115 kb/s
    Stream #0:0: Video: rawvideo (I420 / 0x30323449), yuv420p, 1024x768, 283115 kb/s, 30 fps, 30 tbr, 1000k tbn, 1000k tbc
```

--> yuv420p

But with,

```
cvlc -vvv v4l2:// :v4l2-dev=/dev/video0 :v4l2-width=1024 :v4l2-height=768 :v4l2-fps=30 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=raw,dst=:3333}'
```

the result with

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 1024x768 http://server-ip:3333
```

on the client was not ok.

```
cvlc -vvv v4l2:// :v4l2-dev=/dev/video0 :v4l2-width=800 :v4l2-height=600 :v4l2-fps=16 --sout '#standard{access=http,mux=raw,dst=:3333}'
```

(~12MBiT/s --> 100Mbit)

on the server and the result with

```
ffplay -f rawvideo -pixel_format yuv420p -video_size 800x600 http://server-ip:3333
```

on the client was **ok**!

Comment: Could explain what each of the sections are and how this answers OP?

Comment: Sorry, but i do not understand your question, maybe i missed the topic ...

"Low latency video shared in local gigabit network using linux"

I gave a solution for "nearly" latency free raw-video-streaming.

Nearly is depending from the host, network and clients (performance).

What do you not understand on my answer?

Comment: You posted a lot of commands and their output, but nowhere did you mention this was "nearly low latency", or a brief narrative explaining what the end goal is and the part each step you've included plays in that solution. It doesn't take much, but a little more explanation of narration will greatly improve this answer.

Comment: "You posted a lot of commands ..." and what did you not understood?

Comment: I am not OP. The answer isn't for me. I'm a user of this site interested in making sure questions and answers are clear and good, whether I understand them or not.

Comment: What isn't clear for "you" on commands like cat /etc/*release,  uname -v, 
cvlc --version, 
ffplay -version,  
ffmpeg -version, 
ffplay /dev/video0, 
ffprobe /dev/video0, ?